# How is the gradient and hessian of logarithmic loss computed in the custom objective function example script in xgboost's github repository?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, entropy, derivative, xgboost

I would like to understand how the gradient and hessian of the logloss function are computed in an [xgboost sample script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dmlc/xgboost/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py).

I've simplified the function to take numpy arrays, and generated `y_hat` and `y_true` which are a sample of the values used in the script.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np


def loglikelihoodloss(y_hat, y_true):
    prob = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-y_hat))
    grad = prob - y_true
    hess = prob * (1.0 - prob)
    return grad, hess

y_hat = np.array([1.80087972, -1.82414818, -1.82414818,  1.80087972, -2.08465433,
                  -1.82414818, -1.82414818,  1.80087972, -1.82414818, -1.82414818])
y_true = np.array([1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])

loglikelihoodloss(y_hat, y_true)
```

The log loss function is the sum of [image] where [image].

The gradient (with respect to p) is then [image] however in the code its [image].

Likewise the second derivative (with respect to p) is [image] however in the code it is [image].

How are the equations equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The log loss function is given as:

[image]

where

[image]

Taking the partial derivative we get the gradient as

[image]

Thus we get the negative of gradient as `p-y`.

Similar calculations can be done to obtain the hessian.