# Which is the loss function for multi-class classification in XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to know which loss function uses XGBoost for multi-class classification. I found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093683/how-is-the-gradient-and-hessian-of-logarithmic-loss-computed-in-the-custom-objec) the loss function for logistic classification in the binary case.

I had though that for the multi-class case it might be the same as in GBM (for K classes) [which can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evM6w.png), where y_k=1 if x's label is k and 0 in any other case, and p_k(x) is the softmax function. However, I have made the first and second order gradient using this loss function and the hessian doesn't match the one defined in the code [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/objective/multiclass_obj.cu) (in function GetGradient in SoftmaxMultiClassObj) by a constant 2.

Could you please tell me which is the loss function used?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loss function used for multiclass is, as you suspect, the softmax objective function. As of now the only options for multiclass are shown in the quote below, the `multi:softprob` returning all probabilities instead of just those of the most likely class.

> “multi:softmax” –set XGBoost to do multiclass classification using the softmax objective, you also need to set num_class(number of classes)
>
> “multi:softprob” –same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata * nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata, nclass matrix. The result contains predicted probability of each data point belonging to each class.

See https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest//parameter.html#learning-task-parameters.